# How to override automatic control in Blynk app?

Tags: esp32, code-review, blynk

I am a beginner to Blynk, and have successfully built a simple water temperature control project. It consists of an ESP32, a plug-in water heater, and an AC relay board. The ESP32 controls the relay board, while the water heater is plugged into the relay board.

The code I have will turn on the relay once the water temperature dips below 16°C. On the Blynk app, I want to add a button that allows the user to manually control the operation of the relay. But I am stumped as to how to code it. Since I have programmed the ESP to turn off the relay once the temperature is above 16°C, if I try to switch it on manually at 20°C, for example, the relay will not remain on, because the `if` statement will fail.

How can I code this to have a manual override capability, so that once the user turns on the button inside the Blynk app, the ESP will allow manual control of the digital pin (delay trigger), and will only revert back to automatic temperature control mode once the button is turned off?

```cpp
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp32.h>
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 14        //data wire connected to pin 14
#define RELAY_PIN 23           //IoT relay connected to pin 23

OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS); //instance to communicate with any OneWire device

DallasTemperature sensor(&oneWire); //pass reference to Dallas Temperature object

BlynkTimer timer;       //create Blynk timer object for timed intervals
float waterTemp;        //temperature from DS18B20 in C

char auth[] = "xxxxxxx";    
char ssid[] = "xxxxxxx";     
char pass[] = "xxxxxxx";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  sensor.begin();
  Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass);
  sensor.setResolution(9);           //default is 9 bit
  timer.setInterval(1000L, sendTemp);
  pinMode(RELAY_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, LOW);
}

void sendTemp() {
  sensor.requestTemperatures();      //must request reading first
  waterTemp = sensor.getTempCByIndex(0);
  if (waterTemp != DEVICE_DISCONNECTED_C) {
    Serial.print("Temp = "); 
    Serial.println(waterTemp);   
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V1, waterTemp);
    if (waterTemp < 16) {
      digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, HIGH); //turn on IoT relay
    } else {
      digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, LOW);  //turn off IoT relay
    }
  } else {
    Serial.println("Error: Could not read temperature data");
    Blynk.notify("Error: Could not read temperature data");
    digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, LOW);
  }
}

void loop(void) {
  Blynk.run();
  timer.run();
}
```

Comment: use a state variable

Comment: `if(is_manual){ do new stuff}else{ run old code}` Also, this sounds like a fire hazard. I would have another thing make sure to kill everything if it gets too hot, not just the esp either, those can lockup. A thermal fuse would be good.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly like this:

Make a global variable `int mode`;

Read a Blynk app 3-way switch in the `loop()`;

Set `mode` to the 1, 2, or 3 received from the Blynk app (for ON/OFF/AUTO);

Replace this bit of code:

```cpp
if (waterTemp < 16) {
  digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, HIGH); //turn on IoT relay
} else {
  digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, LOW);  //turn off IoT relay
}
```

with

```cpp
if (mode == 1) {
  digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, HIGH);
} else if (mode = 2) {
  digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, LOW);
} else {
  if (waterTemp < 16) {
    digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, HIGH); //turn on IoT relay
  } else {
    digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, LOW);  //turn off IoT relay
  }
}
```

You will still have to decide what happens when `DEVICE_DISCONNECTED_C == TRUE`, etc, but that is the gist of it.